# When are contracts (like NDAs) binding?

Tags: contract-law, international, non-disclosure

I have a *Great Idea*™ and I've found a trustworthy individual who can help me realize this. We're both private citizens in differing nations with no current employers.

If I get them to sign an NDA, do I have to get it notarized for it to be binding or recognized by court?

Comment: I'm tempted to vote to close this as "too broad".  One of the main series of lectures in a law degree will be on the subject of "when are contract binding" - and that is in just *one* country.  If you ask about international contract law ... you need a paid-for lawyer.

Comment: In particular, in many (but not all) common law countries, you need give something of value in exchange for the value associated with the promise of confidentiality (this can be $1, or even 1¢, but it can't be worthless).

Answer (score 1):

> If I get them to sign an NDA, do I have to get it notarized for it to
>   be binding or recognized by court?

Although some jurisdictions might be more stringent on this, NDAs typically need not be notarized. In any case, it is much harder to pursue and enforce remedies for any violations of the NDA if the other party is located in another country.